# PromQL Grafana percentage

Tags: prometheus, grafana, alert, promql, victoriametrics

I ran into a small problem and can't find a solution.

Grafana has a dashboard that is built on demand

```
rate(http_request_duration_seconds_sum{handler="/createmag",method="POST",status="200"}[$__rate_interval])
/
rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count{handler="/createmag",method="POST",status="200"}[$__rate_interval])
```

You need to make an Alert. Now the first part of the request is the creation time in seconds, the second part is the number of requests themselves.

Alert should be of the form, if the number of create lasting more than 3 seconds exceeds 5% of the total number of create in 15 minutes - then Alert.
Tell me, please, where to dig, where to look?

I tried many options, but it's not the same.

```
increase(http_xxx_count[5m])
-
increase(http_xxx_bucket{le="3.0"}[5m])
```

Comment: Good starting poing will be something like `increase(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le="___"} [15m])/ ignoring(le) increase(http_request_duration_seconds_count [15m])`. I'm not sure with what should used in selector for `le` (where I put `___`): I personally lack good understanding of histograms.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried MetricsQL function [histogram_share](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_share)?

```
histogram_share(3, increase(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket[15m])) < 0.95
```

Please try suggested query above in your alerting rule. It should trigger when more than 5% of requests took more than 3 seconds during the last 15 minutes.

Comment: I tried using your suggested request "histogram_share(3, http_request_duration_seconds_bucket) > 0.05", but I got something weird.

Comment: Added missing increase() in the proposed query at the answer above. @SanchesAngryReut, could you try the updated query?